# Autoloading 3rd party composer packages into Laravel 5 Application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am trying to get my head around Composer. I want to integrate this package into my app: https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

I have done the following so far:

```
composer require thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr 
composer dump-autoload
```

and I have used the library within a Controller method as such:

```
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR($url);
```

But I'm getting the dreaded:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\TesseractOCR' not found
```

How do I make sure that composer autoloads the package and that it is available throughout the apps, for usage within controllers?

Sorry, newbie in Composer here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer *has* auto-loaded the package, you’re just referencing the class name incorrectly.

`TesseractOCR` lives in the “global” namespace, so you need to import it:

```
use TesseractOCR;
```

You can then use it in your controllers etc as normal.